# How to alter a large Azure table without timeout

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to alter a field definition in a large Azure table (20 Gb, 500M+ records)

from **nvarchar(max)** to **nvarchar(16)** using

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MyField] [nvarchar](16)
```

but I cannot find a way to execute this command without running into a timeout. From Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio I get a

*Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. 
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly 
closed by the remote host.)*

after about 30 min. When I run the command from the Azure Management Portal after a few minutes I get :

*Msg -2, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.*

**How can such a long running query be executed on SQL Azure?**

Answer (score 1):

Try the v12 "WITH (ONLINE = ON)" option for your alter statement. See here for examples:

http://sqlperformance.com/2015/02/sql-performance/more-online-operations

Answer (score 0):

you should try

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MyField] nvarchar NULL

Notice the NULL parameter...

Comment: if you need to add NOT NULL a default value.. just add DEFAULT('') before

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MyField] [nvarchar](16) DEFAULT('') NOT NULL

Comment: I do not want the field to allow NULL. ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MyField] [nvarchar](16) DEFAULT('') NOT NULL gives a syntax error. The default should be specified as a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply alter a column on a large table in SQL Azure

Instead do the following:

1. Create a new table with the desired schema.
2. Copy data from the original table to the new table in small batches that do not time out.
3. Drop original table.
4. Rename new table to the original table.

Comment: How online is it? Can there be no downtime whatsoever on the table? Say 5 min? or 1 min? Also what is the nature of the table. Only inserts? updates deletes etc.?

Comment: @Rene Forgot to add you, please see above comment, there is ways to do my solution in a incremental load way as to minimize offline time but it depends on how the table is used.

Comment: It's primarely inserts and reads. There are around 1000 transactions per minute and the table is around 100 Gb. I would like to know it if there is a method to do this but the question is from January and we solved the original problem with a workaround already.

Comment: @Rene there is no easy way to do this that i know. If your table allow you can do the above solution incrementally, and then in the end create a transaction with a TABLOCKX,HOLDLOCK that renames tables and move over the remaining newly inserted rows. But it requires no updates have been performed or you have a rowversion/timestamp. The table will only be X locked for a short amount of time as it copy over the last remaining rows in the last batch.

Comment: You can use insert / update / delete trigger on the new table until the switch to the new table and in the mean time you can scan the old table multiple times (assuming you have a key column)

Answer (score 0):

Well actually there is one option - scale your DB to higher performance tier, do the heavy lifting, and scale it back.

I have S2 database, tried to alter massive table, got timeout after 30 minutes. So I scaled it up to P2, alter done in 6 minutes. Scale back down - you will be charged for 1 hour of P2, which is currently 1 EUR. Peronally, I would give 1 EURo anytime to avoid dirty stuff like creating new tables, moving data maintainging consistency on live system, renaming tables etc...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you see this in V11 and upgrading to V12 shouldn't have the problem of session throttling limits. The other idea is to add a null column / default value and incrementally fill the value and flip the bit when needed, until then your application should ignore the column.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add a new column that allowed null, copy the old column data into it, change the nullability to not allow null, drop the original column and then rename the new one to the old one?

The copy to new column may take time but it shouldn't take the table offline and I don't think the column drop or rename would take much time. Something like this:

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD col2 nvarchar(15) NULL
go
UPDATE dbo.Table_1 SET col2 = col1
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ALTER COLUMN col2 NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 DROP COLUMN col1
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Table_1.col2', 'col1', 'COLUMN'